# Hadith Explanation "Burier and Buried Female are in the Hell"?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

How to understand hadith of buried alive infant girls going to Hellfire?

As Salam Elekum,

I came across a Hadith:

“The woman who buries alive her new-born girl and the girl who is buried alive both will go to Hell.”
[Sunan Abu Dawood (4717) and graded as “Saheeh” by Shaikh al-Albaanee.]

And then there is another Hadith which states otherwise:

“Prophets are in Paradise, martyrs are in Paradise, infants are in Paradise and baby girls who were
buried alive are in Paradise.” [Musnad Ahmad (20583, 20585), Sunan Abu Dawood (2521) and graded as
“Saheeh” by Shaikh al-Albaanee

How can we understand this? Is this a contradiction? Will the buried children in Jahiliyah be in hellfire?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56710/islamic-cruelty-to-the-victims-of-infanticide

Comment: IMHO the translation "baby girls" in the second hadith is wrong as the Arabic original uses the masculine Form which refers to both genders.